Network Disconnects When Adding Docker Container to New Network
I'm experiencing a network disconnection issue with Docker when adding a container to a new network. Specifically, my SSH sessions disconnect, causing disruptions.
This occurs every time I use docker network connect to attach the container to an additional network.
Docker version: 27.0.2
OS: debian 12
I was looking for Docker settings to prevent this behavior. But nothing was found.
Is there a way to avoid network disconnection when adding a network to a docker container?
